# PlatformToolset options

Tags: visual-studio-2013, icc

I installed VS 2013 and Intel C++ compiler 12.1. I want to build my project using Intel compiler, but in "Configuration Properties" -> "general" ->"Platform Toolset" drop down list, Intel compiler is not mentioned.
So, in .vcxproj I added it as my toolset (Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.1). But still I see VS compiler getting used for building. I want to use Intel compiler instead. Any idea?

Comment: Your Intel compiler version is old, 2011.  Older than the Platform Toolset feature, added in 2012.  So sure, that won't work.  Update the Intel compiler to at least version 13.0

Comment: Okay, but one thing. With VS 2010 and Intel 12.1 there is no issue. So if I understood correctly, for VS 2013 I have to use 2013 or higher? And why Intel compiler is not shown in drop down list of "Platform Toolset"?

Answer (score 0):

Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 doesn't support integration to VS2013 as documented in the release notes at https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/77/1c/release-notesc-cwin-update12.pdf (Section 1.3 - System Requirements). Please consider using latest version of Intel C++ Composer to get the integration support to VS2013 (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/fc/dd/Release_Notes_All_2015_W_EN_update2.pdf).